# Primefaces tree with leaf opening a dialog not working

Tags: ajax, jsf, primefaces, dialog, tree

I have a tree with one layer of nodes and leafs. 
When user clicks on a leaf dialog should open with filled in information about that leaf. 
I'm using Jboss 7.1.1 with Primefaces 3.5.

The form is in the master layout.

```
<p:dialog id="mealDialog" widgetVar="modalJS" modal="true">
                <h:outputText value="#{MenuBBean.Id}" id="idValue" />
        </p:dialog>
        <p:tree value="#{MenuBBean.model}" var="node" selectionMode="single"
            selection="#{MenuBBean.selectedNode}">
            <p:ajax event="select" listener="#{MenuBBean.onNodeSelect}"
                update="idValue" oncomplete="modalJS.show()" />
            <p:ajax event="expand" listener="#{MenuBBean.onNodeExpand}" />
<!--                <p:ajax event="collapse" listener="#{MenuBBean.onNodeCollapse}" /> -->
            <p:treeNode type="node" expandedIcon="folder-open"
                collapsedIcon="folder-collapsed">
                <h:outputText value="#{node.name}" />
            </p:treeNode>
            <p:treeNode type="leaf" icon="document-node">
                <h:outputText value="#{node.name}" />
            </p:treeNode>
        </p:tree>
```

This is the error I receive

```
Servlet.service() for servlet Faces Servlet threw exception: javax.faces.FacesException: Cannot find component with identifier "idValue" referenced from "main-form:j_idt26".
```

I've tried with ":" in update but it's not working.

Comment: and if you change update="idValue" by update="mealDialog:idValue" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you Lamq. Your answer was very helpful.

The correct answer is

```
<p:ajax event="select" listener="#{MenuBBean.onNodeSelect}"
update=":main-form:idValue" oncomplete="modalJS.show()" />
```

The id of the form should be in front of the id of the field.
Basic stuff...